# In XHTML 1.1: element 'input' cannot be nested within element 'form'. Why?

Tags: xhtml

This below code is forbidden in XHTML 1.1 strict mode:

```
<form method="post" action="index">
    <input id="_method" name="_method" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

If you want it to be valid then you need to wrap it with a div (or p, etc..) like:

```
<form method="post" action="index">
    <div>
         <input id="_method" name="_method" type="hidden" value="" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How does this make any sense at all?

Comment: The standard is the standard. If you have a practical question, please edit your question to pose one. Why does the requirement for a fieldset trouble you?

Comment: HXTML 1.1 only has one mode: strict. Can you paste the code? I can't understand the question. In XHTML <input/> must be within a <form>.

Comment: @Tae form->fieldset->input, no?

Comment: Yeah.. That's because you need a fieldset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstract_modules.html#s_extformsmodule) and [this site](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/form/) the `<form>` element in XHTML 1.1 may only contain block level elements and `<fieldset>`.

---

As for *why* ... I believe that the reason that `form` may only contain block-level elements is because it is not considered an element in itself, but rather a wrapper around other elements.  There was [some](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:UzY-2VEYsWMJ:lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/1997Aug/0116.html+form+block+level+only+site:http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) [discussion](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:xuZma9YjFm8J:lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/1996May/0192.html+form+block+level+only+site:http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) of this in the w3c's mailing lists some years ago that I was able to dig up -- but nothing that actually answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the wacky world of standards. Sometimes it seemed like the folks writing XHTML standards thought the language would be better if it had more rules.

[HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) is here now.

Comment: But everyone like XHTML as it is.. With lots of rules... Rules make a better World... Without rules === Without web 3.0 :)

Comment: “But everyone like XHTML as it is” — Very true, there’s certainly no-one looking to make an XHTML 2.0 spec. “Rules make a better World...” — Useful rules do. If XHTML had a rule that documents could only contain `<em>` tags on a Tuesday, that wouldn’t make the world better. “Without rules === Without web 3.0 :)” — Eh?